# Pronouncing "vis-à-vis"?

Tags: pronunciation

When saying "vis-à-vis" in English, would you pronounce it **veez-uh-veez** before a word beginning with a vowel sound, as you would in French?

Comment: I don't pronounce the second "s" even if I say something like "vis-a-vis anything else", and I don't think I've ever heard anyone else pronounce it either.

Comment: FumbleFingers is correct. And this is because if it's used in English then the word following vis-a-vis will of course be in English, so the French phrase stands alone. It's pronounced as Mark Beadies suggests below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, the pronunciation in English never includes the second 's'.

[**Pronunciation**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vis-%C3%A0-vis#Pronunciation):
(UK) IPA: /viːz.ɑːˈviː/, /viːz.æˈviː/
(US) IPA: /viz.ɑˈvi/, /viz.əˈvi/

Or roughly, "veez-ah-vee" or "veez-uh-vee" whether before a vowel or a consonant.